# Output parameter with Openquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to insert a record using Openquery and return the ID value,createddate as ouput parameter.

for eg. I need to insert using openquery to a remote server the customername and then retun the customer ID value,created date as output parameter.
insert statement

insert OPENQUERY(TestServer, 'select CustomerName  from dbo.Customers')
select 'Testing'

How can we achive this through openquery.

Thanks

Comment: Please post your insert statement using Openquery without the output parameter

Comment: @Melanie insert OPENQUERY(TestServer, 'select CustomerName from dbo.Customers') select 'Testing'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the only way I could get it to work...

```
Insert  Into OpenQuery([Servername],'Select colToPopulate From [Server].[Schema].[Table];')
Select  'ValToAdd'

Select  *
From    OpenQuery([Servername],'Select Ident_Current(''[Server].[Schema].[Table]'')')
```

SQL was being a punk when trying to use an `OUTPUT` clause.